# Create a column from another column based on keywords

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I get add a third `Type` column? The type of hospital will be determined based on certain words in the hospital names.

```
    Word         Type
    Government   Government
    Govt         Government
    St Jude      Religious
    Catholic     Religious
    District     District
    Community    Community
    Divine Mercy Religious
    St. Luke     Religious
    St. Theresa  Religious
    Islamic      Religious
    Babtist      Religious
```

Data:

```
df = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    Hospital = c("A Government Hospital", "Government B Hospital", 
    "C Govt Hospital", "D St Jude Hospital", "D Catholic Hospital", 
    "Catholic E Hospital", "F District Hospital", "G Community Hospital", 
    "H Divine Mercy Hospital", "I St. Luke Hospital", "J St. Theresa Hospital", 
    "Baptist Hospital")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

# Desired df
df_desired =     Hospital = c("A Government Hospital", "Government B Hospital", 
    "C Govt Hospital", "D St Jude Hospital", "D Catholic Hospital", 
    "Catholic E Hospital", "F District Hospital", "G Community Hospital", 
    "H Divine Mercy Hospital", "I St. Luke Hospital", "J St. Theresa Hospital", 
    "Baptist Hospital"), Type = c("Government", "Government", 
    "Religious", "Religious", "Religious", "Religious", "District", 
    "Community", "Religious", "Religious", "Religious", "Religious"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Is there any conditions

Comment: we can only guess the rules for classification of `type`, so please provide them

Comment: Yes, the type of hospital will be determined based on certain words in hospital names.

Comment: ok, but you must provide those words

Comment: Adding more details to the question, thank you for the great comments.

Comment: Can you try `df %>% mutate(Type = case_when(str_detect(Hospital, "\\bSt\\.?|Divine|Baptist|Catholic|\\bC\\b|Ba[bp]tist") ~ "Relgious" , str_detect(Hospital, "Govern")~ "Government", str_detect(Hospital, "District") ~ "District", str_detect(Hospital, "Community") ~ "Community"))`

Comment: @akrun, it doesn't fully work.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Your update shows there is a key/value dataset, in that case, the regex_left_join in the solution should work (assuming you have all those cases in the keyvalue data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have key/value dataset, can use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
regex_left_join(df, keydat, by = c("Hospital" = "Word")) %>%   
  select(-Word)
```

-output

```
 id                Hospital       Type
1   1  A Governtment Hospital Government
2   2    Goverment B Hospital Government
3   3         C Govt Hospital Government
4   4      D St Jude Hospital  Religious
5   5     D Catholic Hospital  Religious
6   6     Catholic E Hospital  Religious
7   7     F District Hospital   District
8   8    G Community Hospital  Community
9   9 H Divine Mercy Hospital  Religious
10 10     I St. Luke Hospital  Religious
11 11  J St. Theresa Hospital  Religious
12 12        Babtist Hospital  Religious
```

---

#### data

```
keydat <- structure(list(Word = c("Gover(nt)?ment", "Govt", "St Jude", 
"Catholic", "District", "Community", "Divine Mercy", "St. Luke", 
"St. Theresa", "Islamic", "Babtist"), Type = c("Government", 
"Government", "Religious", "Religious", "District", "Community", 
"Religious", "Religious", "Religious", "Religious", "Religious"
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```